# StackExchange.Redis - profile synchron methods

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Following this documentation: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Profiling_v2.html

It works perfectly fine to monitor asynch calls. e.g:

```
var task = db.StringGetAsync("my_key");
```

Is it also possible to profile synchron calls? What I tried:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    db.StringGet("my_key");
}
```

The code is executing fine (it is really executing the task and fetching the value), but profiling does NOT contain any results.

Could it be that Profiling is only built into `StackExchange.Redis` in asynch functions?

I went into https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs to check implementation of `ExecuteAsyncImpl` and `ExecuteSyncImpl` but I could not find the point where the profiling is done

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the example on the page (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Profiling_v2.html) is using:

`ThreadLocal<ProfilingSession> perThreadSession`

When I introduced

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    db.StringGet("my_key");
}
```

the execution of `db.StringGet("my_key");` is taking part in a different thread --> leading to different `ThreadLocal<ProfilingSession> perThreadSession` object.

The solution is to use a global `ProfilingSession` that is not bound to some `ThreadLocal` . Then the results will be available in there. Even if the synchron `db.StringGet()` method is invoked.

Comment: you could always submit a PR to clarify the documentation ...? :)

Comment: @MarcGravell
1. there is already a "kinda" hint on the documentation page with the comment
`// note this won't work over "await" boundaries; "AsyncLocal" would be necessary there`
2. as far as I understand using a global `ProfilingSession` (which was sufficient in my scenario) is not recommended.

So I am not sure how I shall improve the documentation. From my current point of knowledge the documentation seems sufficient :-/